# Python macro code to read variable values from external setup file at QGIS startup

Tags: qgis, python, macro

I am working 100% parallel on a number of different geographic locations with all location data stored in identical parallel folders.

So I am using exactly the same QGIS project file with relative file paths which I copy/paste to all location folders.

But I need to change a few things in between the locations like name and map scale for the layouts.

I am currently managing this manually by entering different values to a set of variables stored under project settings:

```
@Location_Name,
@Scale,
@xmin,
@ymin
```

But it would be much more sleek to add a macro in the project file that read those data from an external settings file stored in the folder for the current location.

I have never written one line of Python code but I assume it must be very simple to add something below "def openProject():"

[image: Python Macro]

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

I have tried this but I cannot figure out how to point at the "Settings.txt" located in the same folder as the qgz file:

```py
file1 = open("Settings.txt", "r")

kom = file1.readline()

QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable('kommune',kom)

skala = file1.readline()

QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable('scale',skala)
```

If I type in the exact location I furthermore get this error and it confuses me a little since I actually thought project variable were stings?:

> TypeError: QgsExpressionContextUtils.setProjectVariable(): argument 1 has unexpected type 'str'

(I have previously used the Atlas-functionality for similar "parallel" situations, but the amount of data will be way to big to handle all locations simultaneously in one QGIS project in this case)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works